# Updating map[string]*struct variable in a struct

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type State string

const (
    // PASS check passed.
    PASS State = "PASS"
    // FAIL check failed.
    FAIL = "FAIL"
    // WARN could not carry out check.
    WARN = "WARN"
    // INFO informational message
    INFO = "INFO"
    // SKIP for tests skipped
    SKIP = "SKIP"
)

// SummaryLevelWise is a summary of results of control checks run CIS Levelwise
type Something struct{
    SummaryLevelWise map[string]*Summary
}

// Summary is a summary of the results of control checks run.
type Summary struct {
    Pass int `json:"total_pass"`
    Fail int `json:"total_fail"`
    Warn int `json:"total_warn"`
    Info int `json:"total_info"`
    Skip int `json:"total_skip"`
}


func main() {

    s := &Something{}
    s.doingSomething()
    // This is one way I tried to update the map[string]*struct variable
    s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Pass, s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Fail, s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Warn, s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Info, s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Skip = 0,0,0,0,0

   // Another way that didn't work
   // s.SummaryLevelWise["1"] = &Summary{0,0,0,0,0}

}


func summarizeLevel(summary *Summary) {
    switch PASS{
    case PASS:
        summary.Pass++
    case FAIL:
        summary.Fail++
    case WARN:
        summary.Warn++
    case INFO:
        summary.Info++
    case SKIP:
        summary.Skip++
    }
}


func(something *Something ) doingSomething(){

    level1 := "1"

    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        summarizeLevel(something.SummaryLevelWise[level1])
    }
    fmt.Println(something)
}
```

The error that I get is

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer
>   dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0
>   pc=0x1091ac4]
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: main.summarizeLevel(...)
>           /Users/i345678/go/src/github.concur.com/test/test/main.go:68 main.(*Something).doingSomething(0xc00000c028)
>           /Users/i345678/go/src/github.concur.com/test/test/main.go:89 +0x64 main.main()
>           /Users/i345678/go/src/github.concur.com/test/test/main.go:58 +0x44 exit status 2

The values of the level string is "1" and "2".

Comment: You have the order wrong, calling doingSomething before initializing a single summary. `&Something{}` evaluates to a pointer to `Something` however its map field is `nil` not to say anything about that map's elements. https://play.golang.org/p/kbkNaIdikH9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func main() {




    s := &Something{}
    // Intialize map.
    s.SummaryLevelWise = map[string]*Summary{}
    //s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Pass, s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Fail, s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Warn, s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Info, s.SummaryLevelWise["1"].Skip = 0,0,0,0,0
    s.SummaryLevelWise["1"] = &Summary{0,0,0,0,0}
    s.doingSomething()


}
```

maps are nil-able. Hence need to initialize them.